RemoteMediaClient.seek() in GoogleCast does not work as expected
I created an app that connects and transmits videos, images, and audio to Chromecast. All other functions work fine, but whatever value the seek t function passes will restart the video.
 MediaSeekOptions.Builder seekOptions = new MediaSeekOptions.Builder();
                Log.d("error", "seekOptions position" + position);
                seekOptions.setPosition(position);
                seekOptions.setResumeState(RemoteMediaClient.RESUME_STATE_UNCHANGED);
                remoteMediaClient.seek(seekOptions.build()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        Status status = mediaChannelResult.getStatus();
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d("error", "status isSuccess " + status.getStatusMessage());
                            Util.postSuccess(listener, null);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("error", "status error " + status.getStatusMessage());
                            Util.postError(listener, new ServiceCommandError(status.getStatusCode(), status.getStatusMessage(), status));
                        }
                    }
                });

I tried logging the position value and found it was in the correct miliseconds format and status.isSuccess() was successful but still running from the beginning.
Has anyone encountered this problem?. How should I resolve it?

I'm getting the same issue. Did you find a solution?

I don't know why but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

by sometimes, do you mean with different receiver, or the same receiver? In my project, it appears working and users appear happy with it.
